# nested generics in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Does kotlin allow nested generics?
In java we can write the following

```
static class P1<T1> {
    class P2<T2> extends P1<T1> {
      class P3<T3> extends P2<T2> {}
   }
}
```

Does kotlin allow nested generics? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What design problem does this solve?  Just because you can write such a thing doesn't mean you should.  Looks unreadable to me.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. But note sure about what is the problem you are trying to solve.

One thing is java static class cannot have generic types. Kotlin object also same.
So if you need to create object for p3 you need object of p2 and for p2 we need p1 object. You can similar thing with sealed class , but you cannot pass type parameter from sealed class p1 to p2.

```
open class P1<T1>{
    open fun doPrint(){
        println("Print Outer class:${this.javaClass.toGenericString()}")
    }
    open inner class P2<T2:T1> : P1<T1>() {
        override fun doPrint(){
            println("Print Inner class 1 : ${this.javaClass.toGenericString()}")
        }
        inner class P3<T3:T2> : P2<T2>() {
            override fun doPrint(){
                println("Print Inner class 2:${this.javaClass.toGenericString()}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you need to use.

```
val p1  = P1<Iterable<String>>()
println(p1.doPrint())
val p2  = p1.P2<Set<String>>()
println(p2.doPrint())
val p3 = p2.P3<HashSet<String>>()
println(p3.doPrint())
```

You can find the output below
[image]